# Create text file from scraping but failed open the file

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am practice web scraping and save content into text file, when I run the code, it goes smooth and no error reported, but i just could not open the file that create and saved the content after it. i am using mac but the tutorial I have is for windows, could you help me with the problem, thanks.

```
import requests
import time
import re


headers = {'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'}

f = open('/Users/pgao/Desktop/doupo.rtf','a+')

def get_info(url):
    res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        contents = re.findall('<p>(.*?)</p>', res.content.decode('utf-8'),re.S)
        for content in contents:
            f.write(content+'\n')
    else:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['http://www.doupoxs.com/doupocangqiong/{}.html'.format(str(i)) for i in range(2,10)]
    for url in urls:
        get_info(url)
        time.sleep(1)

f.close()
```

Comment: You mention you are using Mac, but following a tutorial for windows. I am not sure if that directory structure for your file path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following steps:

> In the TextEdit app  on your Mac, choose TextEdit > Preferences, then
>   click Open and Save.
>
> Select “Display RTF files as RTF code instead of formatted text.”
>
> Then try to open the RTF doc.

Also change your header code to :

```
headers = {'user_agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'}
```

As header is always a dict
 
Hope it helps :)